# What Rest API definition to use when moving items between collections

Tags: api, rest

I am building a REST/JSON based service which has in it's API a couple of collections that contain items. All these items are of the same type.

As an example: The service much resembles a TODO list with collections for items that still need to be done, are in the progress of being completed and are finished.

The API would be something like

```
/todo/new
/todo/inprogress
/todo/finished
```

So how would one define an instruction to move an item from the /todo/new to the /todo/inprogress ?

Basically both collections are as much responsible to perform the move. Should one of them be responsible? or should I make another API called /todo/item which will receive the move instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use the [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method to modify a single item.

`PATCH /todos/:id?status=finished`

However `PATCH` is infrequently used and server/client support isn't always present. You may wish to use `PUT` instead.